# Chaining multiple weak entities in ER

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

[image: ER Diagram]

I am supposed to map the following ER diagram to a relational scheme.

The part that is confusing me is the one on the far right, R2, F, R8, I.

What should the primary keys for these entities / relations be?

My guess (I am listing the primary keys only)

R2(B#, C#, F#)

F(B#, C#, F#)

R8(B#, C#, F#, I#) - redundant?

I(B#, C#, F#, I#)

However I have a feeling like there is a simpler solution and mine is wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
R2 (B#, C#)
F (B#, C#, F#)
I (B#, C#, F#, I#)
```

`R8` is an identifying relationship between `F` and `I`, logically we can think of it as `((B#, C#, F#), (B#, C#, F#, I#))` but since there's no need to represent the same value twice, physically we would record only `(B#, C#, F#, I#)`, and since we've already got that in `I`, we can leave `R8` out.